# ASP.NET WEB API JSON string in my post method always null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Whenever I call my POST method my input is always NULL.

```
[HttpPost]    
public IEnumerable<DEA_Data> SearchData(DEA_Data deaData)
{
    //deaData is null
}
```

I have also tried using and removing `[FromBody]` but didn't worked.

**DEA_Data.cs Class look like**

```
public class DEA_Data
{
    public string businessActivityCode { get; set; }
    public string drugSchedules { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

I am using RESTED Client on firefox to test this. I am passing `Content-Type: application/json` in the header and this as the payload:

```
{
    "businessActivityCode": "ABC123",
    "drugSchedules": "a-123",
    "userName":"XYZ",
    "password":"ABC",
    "message":null
}
```

I have tried couple of thing adding `[FromBody]` - didn't worked. I tried `LIST<DEA_Data>` didn't worked.

**UPDATE**:

The only change i did was make a POST method call to **LIST<>** instead **IEnumerable<>** and it works great.

Comment: My guess is that the json object you're passing in needs to have a `deaData` property. `{ deaData: { (rest of data) } }`.

Comment: Test your code using PostMan or fiddler. Create your request there and post it to your end point.

Comment: You said you got an error when adding `[FromBody]`? What was that error? Were you trying to add the attribute to the method or to the argument (because it's not legal to add it to the method).

Comment: @gunr2171 I did try {deaData:{()}} didn't work, same null values. Well i tried with [FromBody] it is not giving me error but not giving me any values too.

Comment: model binding in ASP.NET Core doesn't work the same way as was in ASP.NET WebAPI. If you need to get data from request body, then you need to use [FromBody]

Comment: @Set : i added [FromBody] and still NULL values.

Comment: Have you tried to stringify your data? `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public IEnumerable<DEA_Data> SearchData([FromBody] DEA_Data deaData)   Worked for me in Postman

Comment: @Barry Colebank Jr did you used same class I mentioned here?? And same Json string?? When I checked it gives me entire string null.

Comment: Same class and same data as you listed above